# Make Two Queries into 1 result set with 2 columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Say I have a table that looks like this:

```
Person Table

ID    AccountID  Name
1        6       Billy  
2        6       Joe
3        6       Tom
4        8       Jamie
5        8       Jake
6        8       Sam
```

I have two queries that I know work by themselves:

```
Select Name Group1 from person where accountid = 6

Select Name Group2 from person where accountid = 8
```

But I want a single Result Set to look like this:

```
Group1   Group2

Billy    Jamie   
Joe      Jake
Tom      Same
```

Comment: This is something that should be handled on the application side.

Comment: This does not involve a application I am doing some data transformation

Comment: Is there any relationship between Group1 and Group2?

Comment: Yeah in the end I want to put them together in one column

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` to assign a distinct value for each row, ans then use a `FULL OUTER JOIN` to join the two subqueries:

```
select t1.group1,
  t2.group2
from
(
  select name group1,
    row_number() over(order by id) rn
  from yourtable
  where accountid = 6
) t1
full outer join
(
  select name group2,
    row_number() over(order by id) rn
  from yourtable
  where accountid = 8
) t2
  on t1.rn = t2.rn;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/aaa17/4)

Comment: You don't need to `partition by accountid` when you have a `where accountid = 6`

Answer (score 3):

I agree you should do this client side.  But it can be done in T/SQL:

```
select  G1.Name as Group1
,       G2.Name as Group2
from    (
        select  row_number() over (order by ID) as rn
        ,       *
        from    Group
        where   AccountID = 6
        ) as G1
full outer join
        (
        select  row_number() over (order by ID) as rn
        ,       *
        from    Group
        where   AccountID = 8
        ) as G2
on      G1.rn = G2.rn
order by
        coalesce(G1.rn, G2.rn)
```